# Generic ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am working on making a game where each level has different mechanics, but I want to keep all the input handling, rendering, etc in one place. My approach is to have a `Level` class with all the needed methods, then each level is its own class (`Intro`, `BossRoom`, etc) that `extends Level` and override methods to change the parts that need to change for each without having to copy over all of the contents of `Level` for each class.
I have a LevelManager class that will hold all of the reference to the levels, and I was wanting to use `ArrayList` to do this.

I've tried using `ArrayList<Level>`, `ArrayList<?>`, `ArrayList<? extends Level>`, and `ArrayList<? instanceof Level>` both when I declare and instantiate the variable. Nothing I've tried seems to work. Is there something is Java that does this or should I just have each `Level` as a variable?

Sorry for block of text, I'm new to SO and do not know a better way to word it.

Comment: Post some relevant code.

Comment: Write up a [MCVE]

Comment: What's wrong with `List<Level>`? What issues does that cause?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should rather be straight. Here is a little example.

Base class :

```
public abstract class Level{
  ....
}
```

**Edit** : You could declare the `Level` class as abstract if you deem that it should not (no sense) or it cannot be (at least one method is abstract ) instantiated in your application. According to your context, it is likely.

Child class :

```
public class IntroLevel extends Level{
...
}
```

Other child class :

```
public class LevelOne extends Level{
...
}
```

Your Level Manager :

```
public class LevelManager{

  private List<Level> levels;

  // constructor
  public LevelManager(){
   levels = new ArrayList<Level>();
   levels.add(new IntroLevel());
   levels.add(new LevelOne());
   ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming, so forgive the novice question, but what purpose does the `abstract` serve for the parent `Level` class? From my understanding it just makes it where you cannot instantiate it. Is that all it does or am I missing something?

Comment: Your understanding is good. It may avoid bad use of the class and it is also a way to clarify the intention of the class. When a class is abstract, you know that it is not enough to be usable.

Comment: @WilliamV in this instance, none. A `class` must be declared as `abstract` if any of its methods are declared `abstract`.

Comment: @davidxxx there is no requirement from the question that the class be `abstract` and as you can see, it just confuses the issue. Someone reading might think that a class has to be abstract to be used as generic parameter.

Comment: @pvg, I introduced the abstract modifier because the context of the question makes the statement that the Level class should  probably not be instantiable : **My approach is to have a Level class with all the needed methods, then each level is its own class  (Intro, BossRoom, etc)** Why allow to instantiate the `Level` class? By the way, it is a assumption based on I understand.

Comment: There is `abstract class` because **it have to be** otherwise compilation doesn't pass and there is `abstract class` because **you should** provide meaning and protect the class from bad use. You could find a discussion about it here : http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96947/why-should-i-declare-a-class-as-an-abstract-class

Comment: @davidxxx The context of the question is pretty poor and  are not really part of the question, which is why the generic declaration 'doesn't work'. You're better off helping the user write a better question than litigating a (possibly completely inaccurate) answer - for all we know the user didn't close a brace, forgot an import, had a bad classpath or many other things.

Comment: @pvg "The context of the question is pretty poor ". No, the context is rather clear. Which is missing is the code which fails and the associated error. But as the need is simple and clear, we could do a simple answer. About if the class has to be abstract or not, you and me cannot affirm but according to what the OP says, it is more likely than the Level class should not be instantiated. So if I had declared Level as a concrete class, it would be probably not the best choice. But I think I would have specified it in my answer. I edited my answer to add the point.

Comment: @davidxxx it's a digression entirely unrelated to the question and the user needs help not in OO design but in asking questions better.